# The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_layer.InputLayer>

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, transfer-learning, vgg-net

I am new to machine learning. I was following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDHpqu52soI&t=2s) on fine-tuning VGG16 models.

The model loaded fine with this code:

```
vgg_model = tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()
```

but gets this ERROR:

```
TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.input_layer.InputLayer object at 0x000001FA104CBB70>
```

When running this code:

```
model = Sequential()
for layer in vgg_model.layers[:-1]:
    model.add(layer)
```

Dependencies:

- Keras 2.2.3
- Tensorflow 1.12.0
- tensorflow-gpu1.12.0
- Python 3.6.0

I am following this [blog](https://github.com/vbookshelf/Skin-Lesion-Analyzer/blob/master/skin-lesion-analyzer-jupyter-notebook%20version%202.ipynb) but instead, I want to use VGG16.

Any help to fix this would be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Version Keras 2.2.4 tf. changed import from import from import keras.layers as layers to tensorflow.keras.layers as layers

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This won't work because a tensorflow.keras layer is getting added to a keras Model.

```
vgg_model = tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16()
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(vgg_model.layers[0])
```

Instantiate tensorflow.keras.Sequential(). This will work.

```
model = tensorflow.keras.Sequential()
model.add(vgg_model.layers[0])
```

Comment: Yes, this is one scenario: mixing `keras.Sequential()` with `tf.keras.Sequential()`. The other problem is with `Input` (which is a tensor) vs `InputLayer` which is a layer, and can be added to a `Sequential` model. However, I got some code which added `Input` to a `Sequential` model, and it worked for somebody else (who had a different configuration / version etc.). (I needed to patch this code...)

Answer (score 12):

Adding to @Manoj Mohan's answer, you can add an `input_layer` to your `model` using `input_layer` from `Keras` `layers` as below:

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import InputLayer

model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=shape, name=name))
....
```

if you are using the `TensorFlow` builtin `Keras` then import is different other things are still the same

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import InputLayer

model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=shape, name=name))
....
```

Coming to the main part, if you want to import layers to your sequential model, you can use the following syntax.

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras import optimizers
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.applications.vgg19 import VGG19

# For VGG16 loading to sequential model  
model = Sequential(VGG16().layers)
# For VGG19 loading to sequential model  
model = Sequential(VGG19().layers)
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to create an InputLayer, you simply must import the BatchNormalization layer in the same manner as your Conv2D/other layers, e.g:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, BatchNormalization
```

*Instead* of importing it as an independent Keras layer, i.e:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, MaxPooling2D, Dropout
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code snippet works for `TensorFlow` version `2.x`. You can run the above snippet by upgrading your TensorFlow using the following command:

```sh
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```