# keras - adding LeakyrRelu on seqauential model throws error

Tags: keras, activation-function, relu

second_fashion_model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.05))

throws error as:

The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found:

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that:

1. You are using the latest version of Keras
2. That you are using Keras
   layers and not Tensorflow.keras layers (per
   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55324762/the-added-layer-must-be-an-instance-of-class-layer-found-tensorflow-python-ke))

Example:

```py
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(90))
model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.03))
```